# JavaScript - Generating divisions in halves

Tags: javascript, if-statement, do-while, modulus

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var expressionBuilder = function() {
    var firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
    var secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
    var operand = getRandomOperator();

    if (operand === '-') {
        do {
            firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
            secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);     
        } while (firstNumber < secondNumber);
    }

    if (operand === '/') {
        do {
            firstNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);
            secondNumber = getRandomInt(1, 10);     
        } while (firstNumber < secondNumber && ((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0);
    }

    return firstNumber + ' ' + operand + ' ' + secondNumber;
};
```

Which is pretty self explanatory. The division bit was suppose to generate numbers such that I would only get division results like 0.5, 1, 1.5 etc:

```
((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0
```

Divisible by 1/2 that is. However, I still get expressions like 8/7. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple misunderstanding of `&&` vs `||` on this line:

```
while (firstNumber < secondNumber && ((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0);
```

The loop will only continue if **both** statements evaluate to true. Let's take your `8/7` example:

```
while (8 < 7 && ((8 / 7) % 0.5) != 0);
```

`8 < 7` evaluates to `false`. Therefore the loop **does not** continue, and those numbers are set.

You really want `||`; you want it to continue if either of those statements are true. Not both.

```
while (firstNumber < secondNumber || ((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0);
```

Comment: It should be noted that using `… % 0.5 != 0` will also easily cause floating point problems.

Comment: Well this made me look like an idiot. Will mark as an answer in 6 minutes. And thanks for the heads up Ingo, my research already made me antecipate it.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
firstNumber < secondNumber && ((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0)
```

As you pointed out, it lets through `firstNumber == 8` and `secondNumber == 7`

This combinations fails the first condition in your `while` and the second one (with `%`) never even evaluates.

This is the nature of `&&` (`and`).

Answer (score 1):

Seems I know what are you trying to, you want to keep looping the number generated until you can avoid the fail condition as you stated in while condition.

lets evaluate the problem at syntax :

```
while (firstNumber < secondNumber && ((firstNumber / secondNumber) % 0.5) != 0)
```

take 8/7 as your example, which means firstNumber = 8,secondNumber = 7
become

```
while (8 < 7 && ((8 / 7) % 0.5) != 0)
```

**do while** will keep looping until the condition is false, so lets examine it one by one.

```
8 < 7 will return false
```

plus, you are using && condition, which if one conditon fails, it will make the entire statements to false.

you need to **both of your statements to false**. so the option is to using OR Operator, which OR only take false only when both of the condition is false.

your solution might be:

```
while (8 < 7 || ((8 / 7) % 0.5) != 0)
```

my notes for you is, there is a slightly a bit different logic when you are **avoiding** certain condition or **searching** certain condition.